# Code does not work for large numbers

Tags: java, long-integer

I'm just starting with coding here, so bear with me, please. I tried doing this simple task (at least it looked simple), which states: "Read two integers, then write out all of them that are dividable by either 2, 3, or 5. My code has no problems dealing with small numbers, however it gets complicated when I get into millions. The program just times out, or takes a ridiculous amount of time to calculate. Help appreciated!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Veckratniki {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long v = 0;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        long a = sc.nextLong();
        long b = sc.nextLong();
        while (a <= b) {
            if ((a % 2 == 0) || (a % 3 == 0) || (a % 5 == 0)) {
                v++;
                a++;
            } else {
                a++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(v);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, the thing is that you're outputting a large amount of stuff once the range gets big. If you actually need to do all that printing, it *has* to be slow after a point simply because it takes a while to print out everything.

Comment: The runtime is proportional to the size of the range to search. Make the range 10 times as big and it will take 10 times as long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to count these numbers you can speed up the program dramatically by using some mathematics, namely the inclusion exclusion principle.

I call N(x) the count of numbers in the range divisible by x.

The answer is then N(2) + N(3) + N(5) - N(6) - N(10) - N(15) + N(30).

I leave it as an exercise to determine N(x); hint: it will be close to range / x.